# Server 2012 - Computer GPO, scoped to user group?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy, adobe-reader, adobe-acrobat

I'm having an issue with server 2012 and setting default file type for a subset of users. 
I currently have a file type association XML file placed into my Domain Controller's sysvol, and it's called by a computer GPO to open PDFs with Adobe Acrobat DC (**Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\File Explorer\Set a default associations configuration file**).

The catch is, I need to limit access to Adobe Acrobat DC to a small number of users and have Adobe Reader be the default for the rest of the company.  This was much easier to handle with server 2008 GPOs, but I do not see a way to scope this computer GPO to a subset of users.

I imagine this being a common issue with server 2012 and wondering how other admins are handling such a situation?

Comment: Hi, Is it related to that question ? http://serverfault.com/questions/833869/set-default-application-for-file-extension

Comment: That seems to be the same issue, but trying to resolve with reg keys does not work since 2012 pulls form a file association XML file.  Working with reg keys to set the default handler worked very well in 2008, but it just doesn't in 2012.

Comment: How about using the [Open With](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732272(v=ws.11).aspx) GPP item which can be scoped to users instead of computers?